# Joining Two (Mulitple) Tables to One Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I have three tables: `DriveMaster`, `Accounts`, and `CenterDetail`.
I'd like to join both `DriveMaster` and Accounts to `CenterDetail` on `CenterDetail.CenterID`.

Would this be the optimal way to accomplish this?

```
Inner Join rpt_CenterDetail CD on (Acct.CenterID=CD.CenterID) and (DM.CenterID=CD.CenterID)
```

Or should I do something like alias a second `CenterDetail` table?

```
Inner Join rpt_CenterDetail CD1 on Acct.CenterID=CD1.CenterID
Inner Join rpt_CenterDetail CD2 on DM.CenterID=CD2.CenterID
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Did you try them? One of the statements won't even execute

Answer (score 0):

Your second guess was close, but no cigar. This should work for you:

```
Select * From rpt_CenterDetail CD
Inner Join rpt_DriveMaster DM on DM.CenterID=CD.CenterID
Inner Join rpt_Accounts A on A.CenterID=CD.CenterID
```

Hope this helps!